Setup jmh without a maven or gradle project
I want to use jmh, but I have a plain java project and I cannot use maven or gradle. I know that jmh is designed to run with maven, but my question is if I can somehow make it work in a normal java project.
This is what I did:
Download the JMH JARs:

Download the following JARs from Maven Central:

jmh-core

jmh-generator-annprocess




Add JMH JARs to your Eclipse Project:

Right-click on your project in Eclipse.

Select Build Path > Add External Archives...

Browse and select the downloaded JMH JAR files.


Configure Annotation Processing:

In Eclipse, go to Project Properties > Java Compiler > Annotation Processing.

Enable Annotation Processing and Factory Path if needed for JMH annotations to be recognized correctly.


Then I followed this tutorial to Benchmark that can be run with JUNIT.
BenchmarkRunner.java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.Runner;
import org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter;
import org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filterable;
import org.junit.runner.manipulation.NoTestsRemainException;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.results.format.ResultFormatType;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;


public class BenchmarkRunner extends Runner implements Filterable {
    private final Class<?> benchmarkClass;
    private final List<Method> benchmarkMethods;

    private List<Method> readyToRunMethods;

    public BenchmarkRunner(Class<?> benchmarkClass) {
        this.benchmarkClass = benchmarkClass;
        benchmarkMethods = Arrays.stream(benchmarkClass.getDeclaredMethods())
                .filter(m -> m.isAnnotationPresent(Benchmark.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.readyToRunMethods = new ArrayList<>(benchmarkMethods);
    }

    @Override
    public Description getDescription() {
        Description result = Description.createSuiteDescription(benchmarkClass);
        readyToRunMethods.stream()
                .map(this::getBenchmarkMethodDescription)
                .forEach(result::addChild);
        return result;
    }

    private Description getBenchmarkMethodDescription(Method benchmarkMethod) {
        return Description.createTestDescription(benchmarkClass, benchmarkMethod.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        for (Method benchmarkMethod : readyToRunMethods) {
            Description testDescription = getBenchmarkMethodDescription(benchmarkMethod);
            try {
                notifier.fireTestStarted(testDescription);
                Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                        .include(".*" + benchmarkClass.getSimpleName() + ".*")
                        .jvmArgsAppend("-Djmh.separateClasspathJAR=false")
                        .result(benchmarkClass.getName() + "." + benchmarkMethod.getName() + "_" + LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) + ".json")
                        .resultFormat(ResultFormatType.JSON)
                        .build();

                new org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner(opt).run();

                notifier.fireTestFinished(testDescription);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                notifier.fireTestFailure(new Failure(testDescription, e));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(Filter filter) throws NoTestsRemainException {
        List<Method> filteredMethods = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Method benchmarkMethod : benchmarkMethods) {
            if (filter.shouldRun(getBenchmarkMethodDescription(benchmarkMethod))) {
                filteredMethods.add(benchmarkMethod);
            }
        }

        if (filteredMethods.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoTestsRemainException();
        }

        this.readyToRunMethods = filteredMethods;
    }
}


CollectionsBenchmark.java
package xoc.stex.jmh;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Level;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Setup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;

@RunWith(BenchmarkRunner.class)
public class CollectionsBenchmark {

   @Benchmark
   public void addAndRemoveToArrayList(Data data) {
       data.arrayList.add(data.element);
       data.arrayList.remove(data.element);
   }

   @Benchmark
   public void addAndRemoveToLinkedList(Data data) {
       data.linkedList.add(data.element);
       data.linkedList.remove(data.element);
   }

   @State(Scope.Benchmark)
   public static class Data {
       private final List<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
       private final List<Object> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();

       private Object element;

       @Setup(Level.Iteration)
       public void setUp() {
           element = new Object();
       }
   }
}

The problem is that jmh generates no classes under in the jmh_generated folder. In my case that is xoc.stex.jmh.jmh_generated.CollectionsBenchmark_addAndRemoveToArrayList_jmhTest for example.
The bin/META-INF directory containas the BenchmarkList  and the CompilerHints  so that part seems to work.
bin/META-INF/BenchmarkList
JMH S 33 xoc.stex.jmh.CollectionsBenchmark S 79 xoc.stex.jmh.jmh_generated.CollectionsBenchmark_addAndRemoveToArrayList_jmhTest S 23 addAndRemoveToArrayList S 10 Throughput E A 1 1 1 E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E 
JMH S 33 xoc.stex.jmh.CollectionsBenchmark S 80 xoc.stex.jmh.jmh_generated.CollectionsBenchmark_addAndRemoveToLinkedList_jmhTest S 24 addAndRemoveToLinkedList S 10 Throughput E A 1 1 1 E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E 
JMH S 24 xoc.stex.jmh.MyBenchmark S 57 xoc.stex.jmh.jmh_generated.MyBenchmark_testMethod_jmhTest S 10 testMethod S 11 AverageTime E A 1 1 1 E E E E E E E E E E E E E E U 12 MILLISECONDS E E 

bin/MeTA-INF/CompilerHints
dontinline,*.*_all_jmhStub
dontinline,*.*_avgt_jmhStub
dontinline,*.*_sample_jmhStub
dontinline,*.*_ss_jmhStub
dontinline,*.*_thrpt_jmhStub
inline,xoc/stex/jmh/MyBenchmark.testMethod

Any help is appreciated!!
